# (Windows 7) Laptop battery drains out ALL THE WAY from 26% to 5% / hibernates

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I've been experiencing a huge issue with one of my old laptops: Toshiba Win-7 laptop - it's battery is acting extremely strange.

---

When using DC (battery) power, the laptop's power drops down abruptly from 26% ALL THE WAY DOWN to 5%, and then it HIBERNATES.

My control panel is showing the normal results:

> Activate low battery alarm when power level reaches: **10%**
>
> - Notification: **On**
> - Action: **Do nothing**
> - Run program: **None**
>
> Activate critical battery alarm when power level reaches: **7%**
>
> - Notification: **On**
> - Action: **Hibernate on 5%**
> - Run program: **None**

If the control panel is showing the default settings, then what's going on?

From 100% to 26%, it drains out naturally as it is supposed to, but the threshold after the 26% is **5%**, and not 25%. In fact, when it drops down below the declared "26%" value, the computer turns off.

And... these are the warnings I never get:

[image]

[image]

---

### *How can I fix this?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likely explanation is that the battery needs to be replaced.
However, before buying a new one, you could try and calibrate it,
as this might solve the problem.

Check first, while booting into the BIOS, to see if you have an entry called
something like "Start Battery Calibration", perhaps in a section named "Power"
or elsewhere.

Second, check if among the utilities furnished by the manufacturer of the
laptop there is one that does battery calibration.

Last, charge the battery to 100%, then allow it to run to almost
empty (1%), then charge it all the way up to 100% again, leaving it time
to rest in between steps.
For details, see the article:
[How to Calibrate Your Laptop’s Battery for Accurate Battery Life Estimates](https://www.howtogeek.com/172271/how-to-calibrate-your-laptops-battery-for-accurate-battery-life-estimates/).

---

Answer (score -1):

If calibrating the battery does not work, replace the battery with a new one. This will prevent the battery from dropping down abruptly from a high percentage to a low percentage.

Comment: Did this come from Chatgpt ?  How is this answer different from the previous one ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1188965)